# How to Write this using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Need help here
I have a csv which is in this format

| Type | ColumnName | ColumnValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Xyz | A1 | A1Value |
| Xyz | A2 | A2Value |

And I need to put it in another Csv in below format

| Type | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Xyz | A1Value | A2Value |

**Any Help would be appreciated**

Comment: `df.pivot(index='Type', columns='ColumnName', values='ColumnValue')`

Comment: Getting below error ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape